# How can i correct ExecuteNonQuery

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPQlD.png)

Please can someone help me out?

Comment: You have 4 Columns and but you're providing 3 Values. -- Use Parameters to specify the Values, don't concatenate strings. -- Both Connection and Command are disposable object (both provide a `Dispose()` method). You can declare both with [`Using` statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) or call `Dispose()` on both (`[Connection].Close()` is the same as `[Connection].Dispose()`), possibly in the `Finally` part of a `Try/Finally` block (the same thing the `Using` block is for).

Comment: Do not enter code as an image. Copy and paste your code in the question and then format as code. Use the Edit link

Comment: Never concatenate strings to build sql statements. Always use Parameters.

Comment: Commands and Connections need to be disposed. Use `Using...End Using` blocks.

Comment: If ID is an identity (auto-number) field, do not include this is the Insert.

Answer (score 0):

Also consider the case that textboxes is empty.
Try:

```
    Dim connString As String = "Data Source=..."
    If TxtId.Text.Trim() IsNot "" And TxtUser1.Text.Trim() IsNot "" And TxtPass.Text.Trim() IsNot "" And TxtEmail.Text.Trim() IsNot "" Then
        Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connString)
            Dim cmdText = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[EzMoney]([Id],[NickName],[Password],[email]) VALUES ('" + TxtId.Text + "','" + TxtUser1.Text + "','" + TxtPass.Text + "','" + TxtEmail.Text + "')"
            Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(cmdText, con)
            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show("You have successfully inserted the record.")
        End Using
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter first!")
    End If
```